# ROR heroku PostGres issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

getting error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  argument of HAVING must be type boolean, not type timestamp without time zone
```

controller code snippet:

```
 def inactive
    @number_days = params[:days].to_i || 90
    @clients = Client.find(:all,
      :include => :appointments,
      :conditions => ["clients.user_id = ? AND appointments.start_time <= ?", current_user.id, @number_days.days.ago],
      :group => 'client_id',
      :having => 'MAX(appointments.start_time)'
    )
  end
```

changed
`:having => 'MAX(appointments.start_time)'`
to
 `:having => ['MAX(appointments.start_time) <= ?', @number_days.days.ago]` 
 and now error is:
  `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR: column "clients.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: I suggest you brush up on SQL's WHERE, HAVING and GROUP BY clauses.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp. This is not a Rails issue.

Comment: yeah, its definitely a postgres is stricter then sqlite thing, just trying to find a solution.... still learning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:having` clause requires a SQL snippet that evaluates to a boolean. `MAX(appointments.start_time)` evaluates to a timestamp

Answer (score 0):

change :group => 'client_id' to  :group => 'table_name.client_id'